# display custom attribute in related product related.phtml

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2

Below is code in list.phtml showing products on category pages. I am looking to use the attributes (RatingSummary, ReviewsSummary) in related.phtml

```
<div class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></a></div>

                **<?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
                <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?>
                <?php endif; ?>**

                <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
```

I found the below code on the web that might be a step in the right direction but does anybody understand how I can adapt it or something different so (RatingSummary, ReviewsSummary) will work in related.phtml

```
 foreach($this->getItems() as $_item) {
         $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getId());
         echo $this->htmlEscape($product->getDescription());
}
```

I would like to use the (RatingSummary, ReviewsSummary) attributes inside the related.phtml Below is the current related.phtml code:

```
<div class="product-details">
                    <div class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_item->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?></a></div>

                <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_item, true) ?>
                        <?php 
                            $listHelper = Mage::helper('colorswatchproductlist'); 
                            $listHelper->showSwatches($_item); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: `<?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_item, 'short') ?>` in `related.phtml` didn't work?

Comment: Wow. that worked. what an incredible first experience with stackexchange. question answered perfectly in under a minute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the blocks `getReviewsSummaryHtml` since the `related.phtml` has all of the methods from `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View` available.

So, in your `related.phtml` add the following

```
<?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_item, 'short') ?>
```